# Resizeable is not working using kinetic.js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs

I am working in one task in that dynamic layer want to do as a resize able by kinectic. layer function.

**For ex:**

When I am click the rectangle shaped button at that time the rectangle shaped would be shown in a canvas.

And it is working also, infact it is draggable also. Now, the problem is coming that shaped rectangle I want to do as a dynamic resizeable but it is not working according to the `kinectic.js` function.

For clearly, let we see the image

[image]

And here is my code for the rectangle shaped

```
function addShape(w,h,c){
    var layerRect = new Kinetic.Layer();
      layerRect.add(new Kinetic.Rect({
          x:0,
          y:0,
          width:w,
          height:h,
          fill: c,
          draggable: true
      }));
      stage.add(layerRect);

var kShaped;
var startRight=-1;
var startWidth=0;
var startHeight=0;

$(stage.getContent()).on('mousedown', function (event) {
  var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();
  var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
  var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
  var ipos=layerRect.position();
  var isize=layerRect.getSize();
  var right=ipos.x+isize.width;
  if(mouseX>right-10 && mouseX<right+10){
    startRight=mouseX;
    startWidth=isize.width;
    startHeight=isize.height;
  }
});

$(stage.getContent()).on('mouseup', function (event) {
  startRight=-1;
});

$(stage.getContent()).on('mousemove', function (event) {
  if(startRight>=0){
    var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();
    var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
    var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
    var dx=mouseX-startRight;
    var scaleFactor=(mouseX-(startRight-startWidth))/startWidth;
    layerRect.width(startWidth*scaleFactor);
    layerRect.height(startHeight*scaleFactor);
    layer.draw();
  }
});
}   

//This click function is for create rectangle shape
$("#textsubmitShape").live("click",function(){
    addShape(200,100,"Green");
});
```